# How can one make a conditional regex replacement in Matcher.replaceAll()?

Tags: java, regex

I have a file path that I break into groups (using a regex statement). Each group is separated by a `_`. Many of the groups are optional groups. It looks like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(path.toLowerCase());

if (matcher.find())
{
    String type = matcher.replaceAll("$2_$3");
    return type.replaceAll("-","_");
}
```

So, let's say I have a path: `hello_world_20190221.xml.json`.
Let us also say this is my regex:

`(.*?)_(ce)?_?(.*)_([0-9]{8})\.([A-Za-z]{1,20})?\.([A-Za-z]{1,20})?`.

Currently, the `matcher.replaceAll("$2_$3")` statement will return to me `type=_world`. I need the replacement string to have condition logic. If `$2` is empty, return only `$3`. Otherwise, return `$2_$3`. Does the replaceAll() function support condition regex logic? I have not had any success with it.

The purpose of this particular piece of code is to consume a path, a regex, and an expression for the replaceAll() function. It returns a group or some concatenation of groups. I cannot change this code to include if statements and the like. *but* I can change the code in any other way, I think. So, if using a different function all together will do what I want, please suggest one. This piece of code has many different scenarios running through it, so I cannot plan for just one scenario (such as putting an if-statement to check if group 2 is empty or not). All that conditional logic must come through one of those three strings: path, regex, or the replacementString. I can change the function all together, but cannot make it explicitly (through the source code) check to see if thing condition or that condition is met.

Am I making any sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your regex to combine optional `$2` and `$3` in same captured group like this:

```
^([^_]*)_((?:ce_)?[^_]*)_([0-9]{8})\.([A-Za-z]{1,20})?\.([A-Za-z]{1,20})?
```

Then you just need to use:

```java
if (matcher.find()) {
    String type = matcher.replaceAll("$2");
    return type.replaceAll("-","_");
}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/H4SEfm/1)

---

**Java code based solution:**

> need the replacement string to have condition logic. If `$2` is empty, return only `$3`. Otherwise, return `$2_$3`

Since you already have a matcher, you can do this:

```java
if (matcher.find()) {
    String type = (matcher.group(2) == null || matcher.group(2).isEmpty() ?
       matcher.replaceAll("$2") :
       matcher.replaceAll("$2_$3"));
    return type.replaceAll("-","_");
}
```

Comment: Sorry... I specifically said that I cannot do if-statements in the code. It would have to be in the stringI put in the replaceAll() method, or having a different strategy all together

Comment: It is not really `if/else` it is ternary operation

Comment: I cannot add logic in the source code. It must remain the same because, as I've mentioned, many different things run this piece of code. They all come with different paths, regexs, and replaceAll strings. I can only control those three things coming in. It must be generic is what im saying.

Comment: ok check updated answer, I have also refactored regex to improve efficency

Comment: Sorry, what is the difference between `(.*)` and `([^_]*)`

Comment: `[^_]*` matches 0 or more of any character is not a `_` but `.*` 0 or more of any character and will cause backtracking is most of the patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Use simply `(ce_?)?(.*)`, and replace by `$2$3`. If `$2` is empty, `$2$3` will be `$3`, else, it will be like `$2_$3` :

```
(.*?)_(ce_?)?(.*)_([0-9]{8})\.([A-Za-z]{1,20})?\.([A-Za-z]{1,20})?
```

---

```
hello_ce_world_20190221.xml.json // ce_world
hello_world_20190221.xml.json    // world
```